# Getting more confused with constructor, method, objects and class

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, private

I am learning constructor and objects and method on Java language. I understand the difference between non-argument and parameter constructor but I encounter a problem on my code that I can't seem to figure out.

I am writing a code for capturing the registration information. I create a `class CompetitionEntry` and inside the class, I insert 2 private attributes as `private String projecTitle;` and `private int teamSize;` and along with one class attribute as `double feePerParticipant = 6.50;` with the initial value of $6.50.

Then I create a no-argument constructor that I have initializes as `projectTitle = "N/A";` and `teamSize = 0;`. An overloading constructor that initializes the attributes using the incoming arguments.

And I create the **Mutator and Accessor method** for the attribute **teamSize** but I want to ensure that it only except positive value. Lastly i create the **method** call `computeTeamFee()` that **return the total fees** by multiplying **teamSize** with **feePerParticipant**.

I wanted my code to get an output for the total team fee from the `computeTeamFee();` method but I can't seem to find the problem and **I need to initialize the object (using constructor)** with the **values "Super Tech" for the title** and **team size is 5**.

And I can only change from the objects method to change the values and display the output.

Please help me. I'm getting more and more confused.

```
public class CompetitionEntry {

     private String projectTitle;
     private int teamSize;

     double feePerParticipant = 6.50;

     public CompetitionEntry () {

         this.projectTitle = "N/A";
         this.teamSize = 0;

      }

     public void setTeamSize(int teamSize) {

          //This part i not to sure how to read only positive value.
          if (this.teamSize <= 0) {

               System.out.println ("Negative value are not acceptable.")

          }
          else {

          this.teamSize = teamSize;

          }
     }

     public int getTeamSize() {
          return teamSize;
     }


     public double computeTeamFee() {

          double totalFee;
          totalFee = this.teamSize * feePerParticipant;

          return totalFee;

     }                  

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         CompetitionEntry obj = new CompetitionEntry ("Super Tech","5");  

         System.out.println("Title: " + obj.projectTitle);
         System.out.println("Team Size: " + obj.teamSize);


      } 
}
```

Comment: You can't say `obj.teamSize` and `obj.projectTitle`, you have to use their getters, since they're private, like this `obj.getTeamSize()`

Comment: In your code you're missing getter/setter for `projectTitle`; you are using a 2-arg constructor -- its definition is also missing, and it needs to have `String` and `int` arguments instead of two Strings.

Comment: Wait I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the CompetitionEntry object, you are giving it the parameters "Super Tech" and "5" as inputs.

```
CompetitionEntry obj = new CompetitionEntry ("Super Tech", 5);
//P.S You put "5" instead of 5 (remove the quotations for integer 
//values as its not a string) as shown above
```

These input parameters for obj ("Super Tech" and "5") correspond with the inputs to the constructor (title and size)

```
public CompetitionEntry (String title, int size) {
    this.projectTitle = title;
    this.teamSize = size;
}
```

The constructor then sets projectTitle and teamSize to be equal to the inputs that went into the constructor.

There are some other mistakes in your codes such as missing a semi-colon in your setTeamSize function for the System.out.print line.

Comment: oooh, I see if I don't put that it won't respond to any of the constructors I input right? but will it be the same for constructor parameter too

Comment: I think you almost understand it. Try to think of it as: The values you enter when creating a new instance of the object are sent across to the constructor, the code in the constructor is then run, where the inputs in the constructor are the actual variables you made when first creating a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you aren't getting any user input so maybe have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp.

Also, your constructor does not have any parameters, so you should change your constructor to:

```
public CompetitionEntry ( String title,int teamSize) {
     this.projectTitle = title;
     this.teamSize = teamSize;
}
```

If you want no negative values, you should check before you create an object, maybe like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String title = sc.nextLine();
int x = sc.nextInt();
while(x<0){ 
    System.out.println("Enter a positive value: ");
    x=sc.nextInt();
}
CompetitionEntry obj = new CompetitionEntry (title,x);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CompetitionEntry obj = new CompetitionEntry();
obj.setTeamSize(5);

System.out.println("Team Size: " + obj.teamSize);
```